# Are we limited to video game development here?

Tags: discussion, site-definition

or would design questions regarding non-digital game design be acceptable as well?

Comment: I am curious what would the question be? What .is context the only thing that really separates a board game from the video game version of the board game is it being digital

Comment: Same question on the Board/Card Game SE (in public beta now) - http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/236/are-game-design-questions-on-topic.

Comment: It's not like you can create a great game without some solid knowledge of the universe of non-video games out there anyway, though.  We're not in a vacuum.

Answer (score 6):

From the original proposal:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2825/game-development

> Q&A site for professional and independent game developers who would like to discuss the various aspects of video game development and design.

Generally speaking the answer is no.  But, if it's a design related question that would make sense in the context of a video game, sure.  There are lots of video games that are essentially board games.

My concern is that it's about the audience, not the question.  Most people on here are interested in video games, not necessarily board games.

Answer (score 5):

I think *yes*, we should keep this site video game specific. Some SE should be appropriate for such questions; either this one or the board game one. (Or a new board game development one, but both this site and B&CGSE are pretty slow already.)

- This site is dominated, and probably always will be, by technical questions rather than design ones. The design questions that do come up are often video game specific, on subjects like good controls or schemas for particular things. Some of the technical content is incomprehensible to me, even as a programmer - I can't imagine a non-technical designer would be able to pick out topics they are interested in easily.
- For anyone designing table games, nearly every question on B&CGSE is going to be somehow relevant, or at least comprehensible.
- Table games have an accepted history of variants and homebrew; every serious tabletop player has done some design consideration. It's not nearly as sanity-breaking as asking the average video gamer their opinion on design and development.
- B&CGSE seem happy to accept the questions!

Answer (score 1):

From the FAQ:

> Game Development - Stack Exchange is for professional and amateur **video/computer** game developers.

Going by that, no.

Comment: The FAQ is somewhat malleable.  I actually added your bold part not too long ago after somebody asked a board game question on here and got flamed for it.