# Are board games and game shows on topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a new idea for a game show and wonder if Game Development is only limited to computer games? Which SE might be more appropriate?

Comment: Can you clarify, what question do you want to ask about this game show idea?

Comment: @DMGregory  Proof of concept. How to design a game show that would be for homeless people in a way that winnings would not be money or sold.

Comment: Now I'm curious what aversion you feel to awarding homeless people with money or things that can be sold. This sets off significant alarm bells. :(

Comment: @DMGregory most if not all game shows I have seen people are already doing OK. For what ever the reason the person is homeless the show does not want to award them anything that would be further destructive to them self or others. Things like food for a year or pay of back child support would be the award maybe rent.

Comment: That sounds like a question for a sociologist, social worker, or other social policy expert, not a game designer. Your question isn't really about how to make the game work, it's how to benefit a specific demographic. That's not a subject on which game developers are the most knowledgeable experts.

Comment: @DMGregory maybe would need to be structured like a like Press your luck but homeless addition.

Comment: I would strongly recommend discussing this with a specialist who works with homeless people before proceeding. This is an area in which you can easily do more harm than good, despite your best intentions. Understand the people and their needs first, then you can start to look for game designs that can serve those needs (if, in fact, a game is an appropriate way to address this issue - it might not be).

Answer (score 2):

Oops, please disregard my previous answer. I'd overlooked past discussions and votes on this matter. [Quoting Tetrad's answer in a previous Meta thread](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/318/39518):

> From the original proposal:
>
> http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2825/game-development
>
> > Q&A site for professional and independent game developers who would like to discuss the various aspects of **video game** development and
> >     design.
>
> **Generally speaking the answer is no[, board games are not on-topic here]**.  But, if it's a design related
>   question that would make sense in the context of a video game, sure. 
>   There are lots of video games that are essentially board games.
>
> My concern is that it's about the audience, not the question.  Most
>   people on here are interested in video games, not necessarily board
>   games.

(Thanks to Alexandre Vaillancourt and Josh for the correction, and sorry for jumping the gun!)

As mentioned above, there is an area of overlap between the these subjects. Many aspects of game design and development apply to both board games and digital games (as well as to game shows).

So, if the question could be phrased about a video game *version of* the game you're making, without changing any relevant details, then it would be on-topic here.

If you'd have to change a critical component of your question in a video game adaptation, like taking the physicality of balance & tangling bodies out of Twister, or taking the athletics out of a game show like American Gladiators, then video game experts might not be the most relevant folks to ask.

[Board game specific design is on-topic on the Board & Card Games StackExchange](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so you can reach relevant experts there if you have questions that *are* specific to physical games, or would benefit from an audience deeply familiar with and enthusiastic about board gaming. (Just note that [tabletop RPGs & LARPs have their own SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

Here, we'll generally be able to help the most with:

- Computer programming, software engineering, and debugging in the context of games (for non-game-specific questions, visit [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) instead)
- Use of game-specific tools and libraries including game engines
- Design and balancing of digital (or digitize-able) game mechanics to achieve specific outcomes
- Publishing a digital game through brick & mortar video game retailers and online stores, and working with publishing partners

If your specific area of interest is outside of this - like in your example of how to help a disadvantaged social demographic - then you might find folks who know more or are more interested in talking about those issues on other sites.